# Unit Test Framework For Geddy MVC on Node.js

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jasmine, geddy, nodeunit

I'm running Geddy MVC Framework on Node.js on Heroku right now with a Postgres database. I can't seem to find any unit test frameworks for node.js that support Geddy. I have tried nodeunit, jasmine and a couple others but none seem to work with geddy (saying it is undefined - I think because it doesn't know how to import all of the required files).

I know Geddy provides their jake test tool but it doesn't seem to work either. It gives me this output:

```
ReferenceError: geddy is not defined
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also looking for a code coverage tool that will work with the unit testing framework I get working.

Thanks!

EDIT: My tests all start with this header to import the required modules:

```
var assert = require('assert')
  , tests
  , Activity = geddy.model.Activity;
```

And the import of Activity fails with the ReferenceError above, so it never even tries my tests.

Here is a nodeunit test I wrote

```
var tests
  , User = geddy.model.User;

exports['addUser1'] = function (test) {
    var user = User.create({username: 'Greg',
                        password: 'MyPassword!',
                        confirmPassword: 'MyPassword!',
                        familyName: 'LastName1',
                        givenName: 'FirstName1',
                        email: 'Greg@greg.com'});
User.add(user, function (answerDict) {
    test.equal(answerDict, {'errCode': 1});
    test.done();
});
};
```

And the output

```
...../test/test-user.js:2
  , User = geddy.model.User;
           ^
ReferenceError: geddy is not defined
.....
```

EDIT: Thought I'd post a direct link to the solution here. After some help on the github issue tracker, I was able to get testing and code coverage to work. I have a small write-up and link to example code too here: https://github.com/mde/geddy/wiki/Unit-Testing-&-Code-Coverage-With-Geddy

Comment: Can you post this on the Geddy issue tracker on github - someone there should be able to help you. http://github.com/mde/geddy/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was raised as an [issue](https://github.com/mde/geddy/issues/337). Please follow up there. I'll update the answer once the issue is resolved.

Comment: Yes I created the issue per Techwraith's suggestion. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain briefly with a sample code. 
Did you try the frameworks [vows](https://github.com/cloudhead/vows) or [mocha](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha)

Here is the full list of testing frameworks. Have a look on it.

[Testing Frameworks](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-testing)

Comment: Thanks for that list. I will try some out. I did try vows and ran into the same issue. I think it might be a configuration error on my part, but Geddy doesn't provide much documentation for tests. Have you had any success configuring vows or mocha with Geddy?